# Typescript array deconstruction values typing error TS2339

Tags: javascript, typescript

I do not know how to give my deconstructed data from an array a type. Is it possible?

### TS error

```
TS2339: Property 'appStatTypes' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

### Code

```
  const [currentState<appStatTypes> = {}] = appState.filter()
```

### Data and Types

```
export interface appStatTypes {
  id: number
  date: Date
  type: string
  creator: {
    name: string
  }
  value: number
  status: string
}

export const appState: appStatTypes[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: new Date(),
    type: 'Typhoon - Wind',
    creator: {
      name: 'Man'
    },
    value: 800,
    status: 'Link no opened'
  },
]
```

Comment: `const [currentState] = appState.filter(() => true)` should work just fine. Predicate is arbitrary fn here. Just to provide something to the `filter`.

Comment: Oh, interesting. My IDE hadn't caught up then I see. Indeeed there is no TS error now...